# What should I store/ Not store in TFS and how?

Tags: tfs

I'm trying to set up a TFS server for our small dev team, and since this is fairly new to me I have a couple of questions.

1) We are developing ASP.Net websites for internal use (intranet etc), these websites currently are not saved with visual studio solutions, they get saved basically as they are on the server and we just update them using Visual Studio by doing file > open website.

So my first question is should I save these as solutions in TFS? What would the benefit of this be?

Im coming from a background of developing WPF applications and have always seen everything saved with a solution in TFS.

2) What should we store in our TFS repository (and what should we exclude)?

At the moment I am storing source code & Documentation but is it really appropriate to store things like installers for VS plugins / small applications or should this kind of thing all be placed on a server someplace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So my first question is should I save these as solutions in TFS? What

Yes, you could create a solution containing the different ASP.NET web applications.

> would the benefit of this be?

Your source code will be version controlled

> What should we store in our TFS repository

Source code, third party assemblies that your ASP.NET applications might require, script files, basically everything that allow to get your site up and running. Documentation should also be stored along with the project. Same stands for installers (the source code only, not the MSI) if those installers allow to deploy the ASP.NET application on the live servers.

> and what should we exclude

Compiled assemblies, but they are automatically excluded by TFS anyway.

Comment: If I save the files just as a folder in TFS they are also version controlled, this is where im unsure about the benefits of creating a visual studio solution vs just using a folder containing the files.

Comment: @Purplegoldfish, a Visual Studio solution can contain *solution folders*. Those are virtual folders associated to the solution and not individual projects.